# Facebook OAuth Enter valid URL

Tags: javascript, oauth, oauth-2.0

I am trying to change app status to Public in App development but i am not been able to do so as it is telling Enter valid URL. 
My Site URL is http://localhost:1337/fbjsapp/.
Domain localhost
and Valid redirect URI is http://localhost:1337/fbjsapp/. I have even set the App Icon

Answer (score 0):

try and remove the / on the end of the url.

if that doesn't work try setting it to https i can't remember if they support http anymore